# Entities Framework 6 alpha 2 - Async Patterns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

I recently have a project with MVC 4, .NET 4.5 and using EF 5.0 (Database First) using the EF 5.0 DbContext Generator.  I then upgraded through Nuget Manager to EF 6.0 alpha 2.  I wanted to use the new async patterns but for some reason I dont have .ToListAsync() available. I am referencing the context in a similiar fashion:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    TestContext db = new TestContext();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var keywords = await db.Keywords.ToListAsync();

        return View(keywords);
    }
}
```

Is this not available in Database First, and only available in Code First? How can I make something like the example above work? I am using SQL Azure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Async. extension methods are defined in EF related `System.Data.Entity.IQueryableExtensions` static class. So you must add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

at the beginning of your controller class file to be able to call them.

Comment: I spent over a day on this! Trying everything under the sun! Until I read this post. Thank you very much!!! *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use Task.Run like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var keywords = await Task.Run(() => db.Keywords.ToList());

    return View(keywords);
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is why isn't .ToListAsync() available to me when it should be?